# Proof of Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $x \in D \subset R^m, t \ge 0$

I would like to prove the theorem of uniqueness of the solution

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u + F(u,x,t) = f(x, t)$$ u \Bigg|_{\partial D} = \mu(x, t); u\Bigg|_{t = 0} = \varphi(x)$

What I do.

Let there are two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$
Then $v = u_2 - u_1$

Subtract the two equations:
$$\frac {\partial v}{\partial t} - \Delta v + F(u_2, x, t) - F(u_1, x, t)  = f(x, t)-f(x, t)=0;  v \Bigg|_{\partial D} = 0; v\Bigg|_{t = 0} = 0$$

$$\frac {\partial v}{\partial t}  = \Delta v - F(u_2, x, t) + F(u_1, x, t)$$
Multiply by v and integrate in D:

$$\int\limits_D v \frac {\partial v}{\partial t} \, dx  = \int\limits_D \frac {\partial }{\partial t}( \frac {v^2} {2}) \, dx  = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \int\limits_D v^2(x, t) \, dx = \int\limits_D v \Delta v \, dx  - \int\limits_D 
v \{ - F(u_2, x, t) + F(u_1, x, t) \}  dx =$$
By first Green's formula:
$$=\int\limits_{\partial D} v \frac{\partial v}{\partial n} \, dS  - \int\limits_D (\nabla v)^{2} \, dx  - \int\limits_D v \{ - F(u_2, x, t) + F(u_1, x, t)\} \,  dx$$

Consider separately:

$$v \Bigg|_{\partial D} = 0 \Rightarrow \int\limits_{\partial D} v \frac{\partial v}{\partial n} \, dS = 0$$

$$\int\limits_D (\nabla v)^{2} \, dx \ge 0$$

If I find conditions that $\int\limits_D v \{ - F(u_2, x, t) + F(u_1, x, t)\} \,  dx \ge 0$, I can say that right part $\le 0$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\int\limits_D v^2(x, t) \, dx $$ does not increase as function depends on t
$$\int\limits_D v^2(x, t) \, dx \le \int\limits_D v^2(x, 0) \, dx = 0 \Rightarrow v(x,t) \equiv 0$$

But how to do it if we don't know anything about F?
And the second question, what will happen if $F=F(u, \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{1}}, \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{2}},  \cdots ,  \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{m}}, x, t)$?

Comment: The well posedness of this seems to depend exactly upon the nature of $F$, i.e. whether it is linear etc, did you come up with this yourself?

Comment: This is a problem from the book.
In the original task, we need to explore uniqueness in three cases:

1) $F=u^3$

2) $F=F(u, x, t)$

3) $F=F(u, \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{1}}, \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{2}},  \cdots ,  \frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{m}}, x, t)$

Comment: The first case I proved:
Instead of $\int\limits_D v\{ - F(u_2, x, t) + F(u_1, x, t)\} \,  dx$ will be:
$$\int\limits_D v\{ u_2^3 - u_1^3\} \,  dx = \int\limits_D v\{ (u_2 - u_1)(u_2^2+u_1 u_2+u_1^2)\} \,  dx = \int\limits_D v^2(u_2^2+u_1 u_2+u_1^2) \,  dx$$

It is possible to prove that
$u_2^2+u_1^2 \ge u_1 u_2 \Rightarrow (u_2^2+u_1 u_2+u_1^2) \ge 0 \Rightarrow \int\limits_D v^2(u_2^2+u_1 u_2+u_1^2) \,  dx \ge 0$

Comment: $(u^2_2+u_1u_2+u^2_1)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u_1+u_2))^2+(1/2)(u^2_1+u^2_2)\ge 0$

Comment: Thank you. A good way. I reasoned as follows:
$u_1 u_2 \le max(|u_1|, |u_2|)^2 \le u_1^2 + u_2^2$

Comment: @ellya 
I have new ideas. But I'm not sure that they are correct.

$\int\limits_D v\{ - F(u_2, x, t) + F(u_1, x, t)\} \,  dx = 
\int\limits_D \int \limits_{u_2}^{u_1}v \frac{\partial F(y, x, t)}{\partial y} \,  dx \,dy 
=  \iint \limits_{D \times [u_2, u_1]} v \frac{\partial F(y, x, t)}{\partial y} \,  dx \,dy 
=  \iint \limits_{D \times [u_2, u_1]} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (v(x, t) * F(y, x, t)) \,  dx \,dy$

Comment: By Green's theorem

$=  - \oint \limits_{ \partial (D \times [u_2, u_1])} (v(x, t) * F(y, x, t)) \,  dx$

But $v \Bigg|_{\partial D} = 0 \Rightarrow
v \Bigg|_{\partial (D \times [u_2, u_1])} = 0$  (It was correctly? )

$ \Rightarrow \oint \limits_{ \partial (D \times [u_2, u_1])} (v(x, t) * F(y, x, t)) \,  dx = 0$
$$\Rightarrow \int\limits_D v\{ - F(u_2, x, t) + F(u_1, x, t)\} \,  dx =  0 $$

And we proved that wanted for $F=F(u, x, t)$?

Comment: It's not all correct, since u = u (x, t)